# Using a variable as an attribute of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

This works:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
    print('LEFT key pressed')
```

Now I try to set the LEFT key for the game with a string variable (by user input).

```
left_key = 'K_LEFT'
```

How can I use this variable as an attribute of pygame?
Something like this:

```
if event.key == pygame.left_key:
    print('LEFT key pressed')
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why does the user have to enter a string? Could you provide some more details about your game? If you want to allow the user to change the key layout, then you can use Reblochon Masque's solution as well.

Comment: There is a settings file, where the user can set the keys (knowing pygame.K_ constants)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
if event.key == getattr(pygame, left_key):
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign `K_LEFT` to `left_key`:

```
left_key = K_LEFT
```

instead of `left_key = 'K_LEFT'`

Comment: The variable come from a user input as a string. Is there a way to assign 'K_LEFT' to K_LEFT ie.: string user input to the same constant?